# C# send Html form action with variable

Tags: c#, html, forms

I have HTML form where I ask for someones e-mail. How do I get the input from the email textbox in the forms action handler?

```
<form name="input" action="sendmail?ontvangermail=email" method="get">
    E-mail: <input id="input" type="text" name="email" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Verzenden" />
</form>
```

action="sendmail?ontvangermail=**email**"
input id="input" type="text" name="**email**" />

I want to put the email input in a variable which I can sent in the action handler? Anyone an idea

Comment: change the method to post so you can retrieve the email value from code behind

Comment: no, you cant do it. may be with JS. Or change name of mail input element and change form method "POST"

<form name="input" action="sendmail?"  method="post">
    E-mail: <input id="input" type="text" name="ontvangermail" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Verzenden" />
</form>

Comment: Thanks it worked! Is it also possible in this way to send 2 or more variables in the action handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use js to send get request, if you are sure for doing some thing like that.
This is basic jquery code to send get request.

```
$("form").summit(function () {
var email = $("#input").val();
$.get("sendmail", { ontvangermail: email });
});
```

For more information look to following link > 
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: I work in Visual Studio with c#, I can't use js or jquery, must be Html or c#